# Как отключить клиента openvpn, при подключении другого с тем же сертификатом?

Tags: openvpn

Имеется openvpn сервер. В конфиге отсутствует duplicate-cn.

Последовательность действий:

1. Подключается клиент А. Все работает, доступ к интернету есть.
2. Подключается клиент Б с таким же сертификатом, как у клиента А. Получает тот же самый ip, который получил клиент А. Все работает, доступ к интернету есть.
3. Клиент А остается подключенным. Доступа к интернету нет.

На шаге 3 клиент А должен быть отключенным, этого не происходит.

Проверено с клиентами на windows, linux и android — везде картина одинаковая.

Конфигурация сервера:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
```

Конфигурация клиента:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote example.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
pkcs12 client.p12
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Уберите строку:

`ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt`.

В этом файле хранится соответствие имени в сертификате и `ip`. Или что правильнее, сделайте отдельный сертификат для Б.